# How to throw an exception in an async method (Task.FromException)

Tags: c#, .net, exception, async-await, task

I just discovered that, since .NET 4.6, there is a new method [`FromException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromexception) on the `Task` object, and I was wondering what was the best way to throw exceptions in an `async` method.

Here are two examples:

```
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            string x = await p.GetTest1(@"C:\temp1");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Do something here
        }
    }

    // Using the new FromException method
    private Task<string> GetTest1(string filePath)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
        {
            return Task.FromException<string>(new DirectoryNotFoundException("Invalid directory name."));
        }
        return Task.FromResult(filePath);
    }

    // Using the normal throw keyword
    private Task<string> GetTest2(string filePath)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
        {
             throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Invalid directory name.");
        }
        return Task.FromResult(filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: The best way to throw exceptions in an `async` method is `throw`. However, neither of your examples are `async` methods.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a difference in behaviour between `GetTest1()` and `GetTest2`.

`GetTest1()` will not throw the exception when the method is called. Instead it returns a `Task<string>`. The exception will not be thrown until that task is awaited (we could also have chosen to inspect the task to see if succeeded without ever throwing the exception).

In contrast `GetTest2()` throws the exception immediately when called without ever returning the `Task<string>`

I guess which one you use would depend on the desired behaviour. If I had a bunch of `GetTest()` tasks I wanted to run in parallel and I wanted execution to continue for those tasks that succeeded then I would use `Task.FromException` which allows me to inspect the results of each Task and act accordingly. In contrast, if any Exception in the list meant I didn't want execution to continue I would likely just throw the Exception.

Comment: That last paragraph doesn't make sense. `Task.FromException` shouldn't be used in `async` methods at all.

Comment: @StephenCleary removed the offending paragraph - thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Stephen Cleary Why not? For example: `private async Task<string> GetTest3(string filePath)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
            {
                return await Task.FromException<string>(new DirectoryNotFoundException("Invalid directory name."));
            }
 ...
}`

Comment: @Bidou: Because `await Task.FromException<string>(new DirectoryNotFoundException("Invalid directory name."));` (the `return` won't compile) is just an overly verbose way of saying `throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Invalid directory name.");`

Comment: @Stephen Cleary Ok, thank you, this is what I was guessing. By the way, it compiles fine with the `return`, but this is a detail...